# is it possible to create a static object in a static method using Java

Tags: java, class, methods, static, bluej

i have a Java assignment and I would like to find out if I am currently on the right track...

**The problem** is that I am to create a new class name Tester and it stated that I do not need any instance variables nor constructors. Besides this class, I have 4 other class which is Product class, Lineitem class, Inventory class and money class.

Next I am to add a method: `private static void addTestItems(inventory theInventory)`.

This method is to allow me to add four different type of items to the inventory. For each, I will need to create a product object and then create a Lineitem object containing that product follow by using a addItem(), a method which i have declared in the Inventory class, to add the product object.

The method is private as it is just a helper for another main method: `public static void test()` In this method, I will use this method to print out some output stating the product that was added into the inventory.

What **I manage to research** is that in such class, I do not need to declare instance variable and constructor. Source: Answer #2 in http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/62694.html.

However, **what I would like to know** is that if I am able to create a static product object in this method. If not, how should I go about declaring the product object to be added into the Inventory class?

**In addition to my curiosity**, by not declaring instance variables and constructors and going straight to static methods, does this mean that this is a static class? Does anyone have a good example of a static class or static method in regards or is very similar to what I am facing?

By the way, I am using BlueJ to do my assignment. I would like to thank everyone hwo read or help me with this problem And if you find this question to be a lousy one please comment and let me know how I can improve on it. By the way.

Comment: A "static class" is just a normal class. The fact that there's any other kind is an abomination (that thankfully you don't need to worry about yet).

Comment: @BrendanLong A "static class" is not just a normal class.  `class Outer { int x ; static class AStaticClass { } class ANormalClass { void meth ( ) { Outer.this.x=5; } } }`

Comment: @emory - This is just a difference of terminology. By normal classes, I meant top-level. I'm perfectly aware of how inner classes work in Java, and my point was that top-level classes are automatically static classes (and inner classes aren't important to beginners, since they exist only to make code hard to read).

Comment: hmm...guys...its complicating now...i think i haven learn any inner or outer yet...haha...this part of the assignment is tough to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just declare a static variable on the class to hold your inventory?

```
private static List<inventory> list = new LinkedList<inventory>();
```

It doesn't need to be in a constructor or a method it can just be your variable declaration.  Since your class is static it will only get initialized once.

Comment: The class itself is always static -- it will only be instantiated once because **the variable is static**.